# Как показать на странице ОДИН из элементов массива, где массив состоит из объектов с заданными параметрами

Tags: vue.js

Есть массив:

```
 state() {
   return {
     items: [...Array(8)].map((n, i) => ({
       id: `${i + 1}` 
     })),
}
}
```

1. На странице я хочу вывести один элемент по определенному id, как это сделать? У меня получается отобразить данные только если запускать цикл v-for item in items, но тогда отображаются все элементы массива, а мне нужен только один
2. Можно ли при таком формате создания массива добавить помимо id, к примеру, параметр name, но чтобы это был массив имен(Аня, Света, Маша) и каждому id присвоилось свое имя или нужно просто руками создавать отдельные объекты и задавать им все эти параметры?

Спасибо заранее

Comment: Про `v-if` или `v-show` слышали?

Comment: Вы хотите выводить в формате JSON ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использование `v-for`, `v-if`, `v-show`, на мой взляд в данном случае излишне.

- Для формирования массива объектов из строк можно воспользоваться методом массива `reduce` добавляя в нем все необходимые поля.
- Чтобы выводить данные одного объекта достаточно иметь идентификатор массива и индекс объекта. Можно для читаемости разметки использовать вычисляемые поля (так выводится `id` в данном примере)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      currentItem: 0,
      items: ['Аня', 'Света', 'Маша']
        .reduce((acc, e, i) => [...acc, {name: e, id: 1000 + i}], []) 
    }
  },
  computed: {
    selectedItem(){
        return this.items[this.currentItem]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    random(){ this.currentItem = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.items.length)}
  },
})
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; margin-bottom: 5px; }
td, th { padding: 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div>
        <table border="1">
            <thead><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></thead>
            <tbody>
                <td>{{selectedItem.id}}</td>
                <td>{{items[currentItem].name}}</td>
            </tbody>
        </table>    
        <button @click="random">Random</button>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Вроде бы уловил суть, только кнопка рэндом не работает в Ваше коде, поэтому не пойму как мне изменить код под мою задачу. Плюс тег скрипт(для чего он здесь?) в начале не работает в моем случае, заменил его на:
```<component :is="'script'"> src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.7.0/dist/vue.js"></component>```

Comment: @Альберт поправил код, там была ошибка со стрелочной функцией теперь все работает, рандом просто чтобы случайно выбрать объект и отобразить его - чисто для демонстрации, что касается тега скрипт то это лишь для того чтобы пример запускался, можете использовать любой подходящий Вам вариант

Comment: Большое спасибо!)